# Notepad++ regex: How to prevent notepad++ to embed unwanted characters in the search?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I recently posted a question about regex in notepad++ because I'm not enough strong to understand all the subtleties of regex.

In a xml file, i need to insert this tag:

```
<?Pub Dtl?>
```

Here's an an example of string:

```
<pgblk chapnbr="53" sectnbr="51" subjnbr="22" pgblknbr="0" chg="u" key="pgblk-53-51-22-0-1" revdate="20200225"><title>
```

or

```
<pgblk chapnbr="53" sectnbr="51" subjnbr="22" pgblknbr="0" chg="u" key="pgblk-53-51-22-0-1" revdate="20200225"><isempty>
```

Here's my first search pattern which works:

```
<pgblk chapnbr(.+?)>(<title>|<isempty\/>)
```

and the replacement pattern:

```
<pgblk chapnbr\1><?Pub Dtl?>\2
```

But, if the tag  already exists, it is included in the search:
The search pattern I wrote finds:

```
<pgblk chapnbr="53" sectnbr="51" subjnbr="22" pgblknbr="0" chg="u" key="pgblk-53-51-22-0-1" revdate="20200225"><?Pub Dtl?><title>
```

**<?Pub Dtl?>** is found but I don't want that otherwise if I use the replacement pattern, I'll get  **<?Pub Dtl?>** twice !

I tried with:

```
<pgblk chapnbr(.+?)[>?](<title>|<isempty\/>)
```

But the result is the same.
The fact to add **[>?]** doesn't change anything.
I well understood that ? is the lazy character but why the search pattern includes **<?Pub Dtl?>** and doesn't stop to the first closing tag ?
It seems unbelievable that it embeds the second closing tag of **<?Pub Dtl?>** and not the first or the third one eg: **<title>**.
It's complicated...
I trained with regex101.com but don't manage.
If someone can throw some lights on the vast oceans of my ignorance...
Many thans by advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can match all in between, except for `<?Pub Dtl?>` using a repeating group asserting not the string on the right that you don't want to match using `(?:(?!<\?Pub Dtl\?>).)*)`

Note that in the example data, there is `<isempty>` and not `<isempty/>`

If you want to match both, you can make the `/` optional using `<isempty/?>` and you don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
<pgblk chapnbr((?:(?!<\?Pub Dtl\?>).)*)>(<title>|<isempty>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `<pgblk chapnbr` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!<\?Pub Dtl\?>).` Negative lookahead, assert `<?Pub Dtl?>` not directly to the right. If that assertion is true, match any char except a newline using the `.`
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 1
- `>` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `<title>|<isempty>` Match one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 2

Replace with

```
<pgblk chapnbr\1><?Pub Dtl?>\2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL4m8C/1)

Comment: Hi Thefouthbirth.
A few words to thank you a lot for the time you spent for me.
I apologize for the delay of my reply.
I tried to understand your pattern by splitting it but I've not totally managed.
I must learn few by few...
I began by (?!<\?Pub Dtl\?>) but I don't understand why there are such matches which are "blanks" between characters (https://regex101.com/r/jL4m8C/1)
In brief, I suppose you'll laugh at me with these examples that illustrate my low level in regex.
Thanks again !

Comment: @pipout64 I will certainly not laugh at you, no worries :-) I forgot to add a breakdown of the different parts used in the pattern, which I have added now.